# Passing values for multi-value parameter in SSRS query string

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have two reports built using SSRS 2005. The first report is set to navigate to the second when a specific field is clicked. 
There is a multi-value parameter on the second report. I need to pass multiple values for this parameter in the "Jump to Report" string when calling this report. Is there a way to pass multiple values?  I have tried Field.Value but that doesn't work for multivalue, it wants Field.Value(0). Or can you pass a parameter that will cause the Select All value to be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Looks like one of the parameters being passed in was Field.Value(0) instead of Field.Value.  That was messing things up.